# PrimeNg context menu passing data issue

Tags: angular, primeng, angular6

I am using PrimeNg's context menu v6.0.1, the problem is the documentation is not clear and I cannot find it over the web as well on how to pass data to command function e.g.:

I have 10 objects rendered on screen and context menu is attached to all of these objects, now if I click on menu item I want to get the id of the target object on which the context menu is rendered, how can this be accomplished?

```
<div id="block-container" *ngFor="let block of blocks">

    <!-- where to attach this block object ??? -->

    <p-contextMenu appendTo="body" 
      [target]="blockContextMenu" 
      [model]="contextMenuItems">
    </p-contextMenu>

    <div #blockContextMenu>
       Some implementation...
    </div>
</div>
```

and following is my items model:

```
this.contextMenuItems = [
  {
    label: 'Trip Details',
    command: (event) => {
      // event doesn't contain anything useful,
      // and only has the clicked menu item specific information.
  }}
];
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
  @ViewChild('copyMenu') copyMenu: ContextMenu;
  
    onLinkRightClicked(content: string, e: any): void {

    if (this.copyMenu) {
      let model: MenuItem[] = [];
      model.push({ label: 'Action', command: (event) => this.doAction(content) });
      this.copyMenu.model = model;
      this.copyMenu.show(e);
    }
  }
  
  doAction(content){
    // here 
  }
```

```html
<div #blockContextMenu (contextmenu)="onLinkRightClicked(content, $event)">
       Some implementation...
</div>

<p-contextMenu appendTo="body" #targetContextMenu>
</p-contextMenu>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to bind the a model to the context menu, just like in the documentation, but then programmatically change the model & open the menu.

**1**. Remove the `target` attribute from `p-contextMenu` - this would prevent out-of-the-box menu toggle mechanism.(`<p-contextMenu #contextMenu appendTo="body" [model]="contextMenuItems"></p-contextMenu>`)

**2**. Instead of referencing (`<div #blockContextMenu></div>`), use event binding (`<div (contextmenu)="openContextMenu($event, dataYouNeedToPass)"></div>`)

**3**. In your component, use `@ViewChild` to get access to the context menu and declare an empty model:

```
@ViewChild('contextMenu', { static: false }) contextMenu: ContextMenu;
contextMenuItems: MenuItem[] = [];
```

**4**. Add the `openContextMenu` function to programmatically change the model & open the context menu:

```
openContextMenu(event: MouseEvent, dataYouNeedToPass: any): void {
  this.contextMenuItems = [{
    label: 'Action One',
    command: (event) => this.doActionOne(dataYouNeedToPass)
  },
  {
    label: 'Action Two',
    command: (event) => this.doActionTwo(dataYouNeedToPass)
  }];
  this.documentActionContextMenu.show(event);
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a proper implementation of context menu with primeng you need to add

```
[contextMenu]="cm"
```

in an element which you want to show, for example, you want context menu over your div you need to mention

```
<div id="block-container" *ngFor="let block of blocks" [contextMenu]="cm"></div>
```

also in the p-contextMenu element, you need to do mentioned the variable of context menu from your div like

hope this helps.

Comment: was this a thing in 2018? It's not working as you describe.

Answer (score 0):

We can get data on the PrimeNG context Menu Item click by just pushing data to command **property** callback function.

Below example code is also an example of the dynamic context menu creation with the Nth level.

For Example -

```
[
  {
    "ID": 1,
    "TITLE": "parent1",
    "SUBMENU": [
      {
        "ID": 2,
        "SUBMENU": [
          {
            "ID": 3,
            "SUBMENU": [
              {
                "ID": 4,
                "TITLE": "Child 1"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "ID": 13,
            "SUBMENU": [
              {
                "ID": 5,
                "TITLE": "Child 3"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "ID": 6,
            "SUBMENU": [
              {
                "ID": 7,
                "SUBMENU": [
                  {
                    "ID": 8,
                    "TITLE": "Child 4"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "ID": 9,
                "SUBMENU": [

                ]
              }
            ],

          },
          {
            "ID": 10,
            "SUBMENU": [
              {
                "SUBMENU": [

                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],

      }
    ],

  },
  {
    "ID": 11,
    "TITLE": "parent2",
    "SUBMENU": [
      {
        "ID": 12,
        "TITLE": "Child 4"
      }
    ],

  }
]
```

From the above JSON, I created the PrimeNG context menu Items.

```
createContextMenuRecursive(object: any[]): MenuItem[] {
    if (object) {
      let menuList: MenuItem[] = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
        if (object[i].ITEMS && object[i].ITEMS.length > 0) {
          let returnedList = this.createContextMenuRecursive(object[i].ITEMS);
          menuList.push(this.createMenuItem(object[i], returnedList));
        }
        else {
          menuList.push(this.createMenuItem(object[i]));
        }
      }
      return menuList;
    }
  }
```

The below function is used to create the PrimeNG context menu Item, where parameter data: any represents the data we need to use in command function.

```
createMenuItem(data: any, menuItems: MenuItem[] = []): MenuItem {
    if (menuItems.length > 0) {
      return { label: data.TITLE, items: menuItems, command: (event) => this.docGridContextMenuItemClick(event, data) };
    }
    else {
      return { label: data.TITLE, command: (event) => this.docGridContextMenuItemClick(event, data) };
    }
  }
```

Context menu item click event handler where we use the data.

```
docGridContextMenuItemClick(event: any, data: any) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As the "Id's" are unique you need only pass it with the command() function:

https://primeng-panelmenu-return-id.stackblitz.io

```
  items: MenuItem[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.items = [
      { label: "Rename", id: "1", command: () => this.onClickMenuItem("1") },
      { label: "Delete", id: "2", command: () => this.onClickMenuItem("2") },
      { label: "Add", id: "3", command: () => this.onClickMenuItem("3") }
    ];
  }

  onClickMenuItem(id: string) {
    console.log(id);
  }
```